# Private (#) getter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, private, getter-setter, ecmascript-next

Are private getters/setters planned to be supported in JavaScript?

```js
class Next {
  #private = 0
  get #computed() { // SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    return this.#private + 1
  }
}
```

**If not**, what is the rationale behind that?
I suppose implementation wouldn't be a hurdle. Are there objections to the functionality itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update - ECMAScript 2021**

With the latest es2021 version Private getters and setters are also possible.

Your code should be valid now:

```
class Next {
  #private = 0
  get #computed() { 
   return this.#private + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they're part of the [private methods and accessors proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods), a follow-on to [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). The syntax is exactly as you've shown it. JavaScript engines are actively working to implement them, and Babel has working transpilation for them via the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` plugin.

Those two proposals are joined by the [static class features proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/) which covers static public properties, static private fields, and static private methods (including accessors).